# echo php function inside html tag

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a function in my controller that retrieves `User name` here:

```
public function getUserName(){
     $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     return $this->user_model->sban_name($user_id);
 }
```

Now, what I want is to put it directly inside an HTML tag like this,

```
<a href="#"><?php echo getUserName();?></a>
```

But, it's not working. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What output are you getting instead?

Comment: Define a `helper` and load it in your `controller` and call it in your `view`.

Comment: Why don't you pass data within a view as like `redirect('your_view',$data);`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, i dont get your point sir.

Comment: CI provides a way to call your function in your view by creating your own helper but in your context simply follow a way of @GluePear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `username` to your view via the controller. You can't access controller functions in your view. So in the controller that loads the view, do something like this:

```
$data['username'] = $this->getUserName();
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

Then in your view you can simply `echo` the `username`:

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $username ?></a>
```

Comment: something like this? $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/header_view',$data);

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you're loading the view like that anyway? For more info on passing data to views, see the [Codeigniter manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: i tried, but it says, undefined function getUserName();

Comment: In my example, the function `getUserName` has to be in the same controller as the function that loads the view. Is it?